# Oracle OCI8 PHP Debian Encoding error

Tags: php, oracle, apache, .htaccess, encoding

i'm despaired of the encoding stuff using a debian 8 server with Instantclient 12.2, php 5.6 and oci8(2.0.12).

I had encoding issues in the php sites itself which i solved by setting the php encoding to `ISO-8859-1` in `php.ini`. -> So encoding, including all european chars, works for php.

Now my problem is that the data I retrieve from our oracle12c database isn't encoded correctly. So i get

```
a for ä
o for ö
u for ü
? for ß
```

When saving from php to Database, the same thing happens.

in sqlplus64 client the data is encoded correctly so i guess it has something to do with oci8.

**What i tried:**

I already set the `NLS_LANG` parameter to `GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8ISO8859P1` and `GERMAN_GERMANY.UTF-8`, tried to give `oci_connect()` a charset manually, tried all encoding options for `apache2.conf` and `php.ini`, tried to overwrite eventually loaded configs through `.htaccess` file and stuff. But none of that worked.

Maybe someone knows a way out?

Comment: No, as i mentioned, I tried to set this manually. When nothing is set, NLS_LANG parameter is taken.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

`putenv("NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8ISO8859P1");`

before `oci_connect()`

I have absolutely no idea why this is working but I guess the apache can't access the parameters i set via `/etc/profile` file

Comment: [/etc/profile](http://bencane.com/2013/09/16/understanding-a-little-more-about-etcprofile-and-etcbashrc/) appears to be used in interactive user shells. The weird bit is charset in `oci_connect()` being ignored :-?